# Switch Parameter and an If Statement

Tags: powershell, parameters, switch-statement, powershell-5.0

I am trying to use the value of a switch parameter as the trigger to write to a csv file if the parameter is called with the script from the command line.  However, with my current code the csv file is created whether I include the parameter or not.  What's up with that?

Also, is there a better way to handle my else/if else/if else section?

```
[CmdletBinding()]
param (
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
    [string]$dir,
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
    [int]$days,
    [switch]$csv=$false
)

Process {
    Clear-Host
    $totSize = 0
    $totFiles = 0
    $modDate = (Get-date).AddDays(-$days).Date
    $modfiles = Get-ChildItem -Path $dir -Recurse -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue | Where-Object { $_.LastWriteTime -ge $modDate } 
    If ($csv = $true){
        $modfiles | Select-Object -Property FullName, Length,LastWriteTime | Export-Csv -Path .\modFiles.csv -NoTypeInformation
    }
    foreach ($file in $modfiles){
        $totFiles = $totFiles + 1
        $totSize = $totSize + $file.Length 
    }

    If ($totSize -lt 1MB){
        $outSize = $totSize/1KB
        $unit = "KB"
    }
    elseif (($totSize -ge 1MB) -and ($totSize -lt 1GB)){
        $outSize = $totSize/1MB
        $unit = "MB"   
    }
    elseif ($totSize -ge 1GB){
        $outSize = $totSize/1GB
        $unit = "GB" 
    } 

    $outRound = [math]::Round($outSize,2)
    Write-Host $totFiles "Files"
    Write-Host $outRound $unit
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Two problems.

1. Do not specify a default value for a [switch] parameter.  It will mess you up.  Leave it off, and it will be $true if specified, and $false if 
   not.
2. When testing a logical value, such as an If statement, do not use the assignment equals (=), use the comparison equals (-eq).

```
If ($csv -eq $true){
    $modfiles | Select-Object -Property FullName, Length,LastWriteTime | Export-Csv -Path .\modFiles.csv -NoTypeInformation
}
```

EDIT (Thanks @Scepticalist): Further, if the variable you are testing already holds a [bool] value, or can be implicitly converted to [bool], you don't even need the `-eq $true` part of the comparison, so:

```
If ($csv){
        $modfiles | Select-Object -Property FullName, Length,LastWriteTime | Export-Csv -Path .\modFiles.csv -NoTypeInformation
    }
```

Comment: Thank you very much.  This place has been great helping me learn.

Comment: I wasn't going to leave you hanging.  There's a countdown timer of X minutes from posting to being able to accept an answer.  You were quick, my friend.

Comment: I literally had zero idea about that timer.  Learn something new every day, eh?  :)  Thanks very much, and glad I could assist.  I am *constantly* putting the `=` in for the `-eq` myself, and it really messes me up.

Comment: In most situations you don't need "-eq" if you're testing for true/false. A simple "If ($csv) {" will suffice.

Comment: Too right @Scepticalist.  My example has been edited to reflect this.

Comment: @Scepticalist, thanks for helping me make my code just a little bit cleaner.